PHP to Drupal Node with HTML
I am working on a custom module with Drupal.
My module needs to let the user upload a PDF file, and then the modules creates a Node of type:decision and in the field_decision_text I want to put the contents of the PDF in HTML structure so that I can keep all the formatting of the PDF as it is.
I have tried some libraries such as TCPDF and Dompdf but I didn't have any success. Maybe I was not using them right.
So basically I have created a form where the user uploads a PDF, and then when the form is submitted, I run this function which puts the content of the PDF in the Node, as text.
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Get the uploaded file.
    $file = $form_state->getValue('pdf_file');

    // Validate the uploaded file.
    $validators = [
      'file_validate_extensions' => ['pdf'],
    ];

    $new_file = file_save_upload('pdf_file', $validators);

    if ($new_file) {
      // Extract text from the PDF file.
      $pdf_uri = $new_file[0]->getFileUri();
      $pdf_content = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($pdf_uri);
      $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
      $pdf = $parser->parseFile($pdf_content);
      $text = $pdf->getText();
      // Create a new node and save the extracted text to the field.
      $node = Node::create([
        'type' => 'decision',
        'title' => $new_file[0]->getFilename(), // Use the file name as the node title.
        'field_attachment' => [
          'target_id' => $new_file[0]->id(), // Attach the uploaded file to a file field.
        ],
        'field_decision_text' => $text, // Save the extracted text to the field.
      ]);

      // Save the node.
      $node->save();

      // Optionally, redirect the user to the created node.
      $url = $node->toUrl();
      $form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
    } else {
      $form_state->setErrorByName('pdf_file', $this->t('Please upload a valid PDF file.'));
    }
  }

So I have the main functionality I'm looking for, I just need to convert somehow the PDF to HTML and then pass it in the the field of the Node but I am not very sure how. Any help will be highly apprciated.

To be clear, you aren't having any problems as it relates to Drupal right now, you are purely having problems extracting PDF contents, right?

If I'm correct, my recommendation is to ignore Drupal for now, and focus solely on your PDF extraction. There's no HTML inside of the PDF, so any "extract with formatting" will be semi-arbitrary. PDFs don't even have the concept of paragraphs, they just happen to have lines that are visually near to each other. You might want to look at a tool such as PDFMiner which does a pretty good job of translating some/most of the formatting to HTML

@ChrisHaas Yes you are right. I can succesfully create a node, I just want to get the HTML structure out of the PDF to give it to my Node, instead of just the Text

The reason I asked is because I wanted to be sure that basically none of the code you posted was related to your problem. If you really need HTML, then you'll want to look at PDFMiner or pdftohtml or similar. You probably won't find anything that doesn't ultimately shell-out or open a process to extract using some binary that you need to install or possibly compile for your platform.

@ChrisHaas Yes I understand what you mean. I have tried using pdftohtml, which does a really good job and exactly what I need, but there is a problem. The problem is that the command is in this format: pdftohtml -s -i -noframes -stdout UnprocessedDecision.pdf where a file is taken as a paramenter. Well in Drupal, as shown in the code above I don't really have the file in a directory and I can't execute the command in that directory. Or at least I don't know how to do that. So this still doesn't work in my scenario.

Doesn’t Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($pdf_uri); get you the absolute path to the file, so then you could use $pdf_content?

@ChrisHaas In the above code, I would get from $pdf_uri: "temporary://helloworld_0.pdf" and from $pdf_content: "/var/www/html/tmp/helloworld_0.pdf".How do you suggest using the pdf_content?

@ChrisCosta 127 means binary was not found... try using the absolute path of that binary in your system instead of just using pdftohtml. maybe usr/bin/ ? but that's the route.. and yet you didn't say if you installed it. You are only talking about libraries. Yet if the node where this script is running has an available shell, try manually instead of using the script to run which just to narrow down the coordinates

Here's a quick function I put together based on some other code I've used to interact with these tools. I'm a big fan of proc_open in general because you get access to both stdOut and stdIn, and sometimes command programs write error information to one or the other, or both.
This function is pure PHP so you should be able to run it in Drupal, Symfony, WordPress, etc., although you'll probably want to add platform-specific things like logging.
You should be able to pass $pdf_content to this function which will return the contents of a the PDF, or throw an exception.
I would extend this by creating a custom exception that stores both stdErr and stdOut, as well as the return value of the command, but I'll leave that.
If you run into problems with this, make sure to inspect stdErr. You might see something about "the command pdftohtml is not a command" or similar, and in that case you might need to provide the absolute path to the binary, or possibly adjust permissions.
function convertPdfToHtml(string $inputFileName): string
{
    // Two ways to run this, the array version was added in 7.4 but might
    // run into some platform weirdness, especially on Windows.
    // You might also want to specify the absolute path to pdftohtml.

    // You can either build a string and escape manually
    //$cmd = 'pdftohtml';
    //$cmd .= ' -i -s -noframes -stdout';
    //$cmd .= ' '.escapeshellarg($inputFileName);
    //$cmd .= ' '.escapeshellarg($tmpNameWithExtension);

    // OR, you can use an array and it will be escaped for you
    $cmd = [
        'pdftohtml',
        '-i',
        '-s',
        '-noframes',
        '-stdout',
        $inputFileName,
    ];

    // Output streams to read errors
    $descriptorspec = [
        1 => ['pipe', 'w'],  // stdout
        2 => ['pipe', 'w'],  // stderr
    ];

    // Handle high-level failure somehow
    if (!$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes)) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Error');
    }

    // Get both stdOut and stdErr as strings, just in case we need to look at them
    $stdOut = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    $stdErr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

    // Cleanup
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    // Check the return value
    if ($return_value = proc_close($process)) {

        // Exit code from https://www.xpdfreader.com/pdftohtml-man.html#EXIT%20CODES
        $msg = match ($return_value) {
            1 => 'Error opening a PDF file',
            2 => 'Error opening an output file',
            3 => 'Error related to PDF permissions',
            98 => 'Out of memory',
            99 => 'Other error',
            default => 'Unknown return_value',
        };

        // Do something here
        throw new RuntimeException($msg.PHP_EOL.$stdErr);
    }

    return $stdOut;
}

Edit
For debugging purposes, here's a simpler version that just spits some information out. I've removed the array version in favor of the string version. There's notes about it bypassing the shell in the array version. I'm not as familiar with kint, so this is just using var_dump, but change as needed.
If which finds an executable it should return 0 and stdOut should be the absolute path to it. If which cannot find an executable it should return 1 and stdErr will be where it looked.
function debugPdfToHtml()
{
    $cmd = 'which pdftohtml';

    // Output streams to read errors
    $descriptorspec = [
        1 => ['pipe', 'w'],  // stdout
        2 => ['pipe', 'w'],  // stderr
    ];

    // Handle high-level failure somehow
    if (!$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes)) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Error');
    }

    // Get both stdOut and stdErr as strings, just in case we need to look at them
    $stdOut = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    $stdErr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

    // Cleanup
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);

    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    var_dump($return_value, $stdOut, $stdErr);
}

debugPdfToHtml();


I really appreciate your help. i got some problems implementing this in my code that maybe you will be able to help me. So I run this function passing as an argument "/var/www/html/tmp/helloworld_0.pdf". While the code executes both $stdOut and $stdErr are: "". Also I get this error: Unknown return_value in Drupal\decision_import\Form\DecisionImportForm->convertPdfToHtml() which I suppose says that the command didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

I also tried $cmd = ['cat', $inputFileName,]; to see if there's problem with the execution of the command. This succesfully printed me the contents of the file so I know that the proc_open() is working correctly. Also checking the $return_value, it equals 127 when I try to run the pdftohtml command.

Also no that when trying the command pdftohtml -i -s -noframes -stdout helloworld.pdf (the same pdf as the one that I am trying to convert in Drupal), I succesfully get the desired html code output in the console.

You’ll need to inspect the return value. I pulled six above from the referenced documentation, but there’s apparently more. You can just concatenate it onto the exception to see it

I used kint($return_value); to inspect it, and what I get is 127.

That might mean it cannot find the binary. Try running the command which pdftohtml through this and see what stdout and stderr say

Using the command $cmd2 = ['which','pdftohtml',]; and kint($stdOut); kint($stdErr); I get on both the empty String "". And as $return_value I get 1.

Basically, this is what I get from $pipes:
  1 => stream resource @34 ▼
    timed_out: false
    blocked: true
    eof: false
    stream_type: "STDIO"
    mode: "r"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: false
    options: []
  }
  2 => stream resource @35 ▼
    timed_out: false
    blocked: true
    eof: false
    stream_type: "STDIO"
    mode: "r"
    unread_bytes: 0
    seekable: false
    options: []
  }
]


@ChrisCosta, I've updated with another function to debug this further, just to make sure we can find the binary in the first place.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
